# Properly setup UIView subclass with IBOutlets

Tags: ios, swift, subclass

#### Background

I subclassed `UIView` in my class `MyView`. I created `IBOutlet`s attached to the subclass. When calling the `setup()` method to do some setup from `init()`, I find that the outlets are not yet initialized, and therefor `nil`.
I tried overriding `layoutSubviews()` which worked, but as I read, `layoutSubviews()` is called *every time* after a new view is added as child so that does not seem to be the best practice.

I came up with this solution: call `setup()` separately - not from within the class but later, in `viewDidLoad()` of the `ViewController` `MyView` is in. That seems to work, but is rather inconvenient, I think.

#### Code

Here's a short summary of my code:

```
class MyView: UIView {
    @IBOutlet weak var button: UIButton!
    
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }

    func setup() {
        if button == nil { print("nil") } //prints "nil"
    }
}
```

---

#### Question

Essentially, the question is at which point *from inside the class* I should call the `setup()` method.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your setup needs to go in `awakeFromNib` instead of `init`

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // Your setup here
    setup()
}
```

`awakeFromNib` is called after the view has been loaded from the nib, and after all the outlets etc have been connected. `init(coder:)` is called after the view is created, but the rest of the views haven't been created / connected yet.

However, using `init(frame:)` to create a view means that `awakeFromNib` *isn't* called (obvious really - there isn't a nib in this case!) so you might also have to put some setup code in there too - depends entirely on your use case.

Comment: Ahhh, thanks! One might think *awake from nib* sounds self-explanatory, now that I know of it, it does, ha.

Comment: This is the correct answer. (Voted). A view's outlets are never connected in it's init method.

Comment: I figured they weren't. But I didn't know at which point they are. @DuncanC - I think I'll actually post that in documentation…

Comment: Normally you handle outlet connections in a view controller. In that case you use the `viewDidLoad()` function. At the view level, though, you need to use another approach, since`viewDidLoad()` is a view controller instance method. If your views are being loaded from a storyboard or XIB then `awakeFromNib()` is there right place. If you're creating your views from code, however, `awakeFromNib()` doesn't get called, as dean pointed out in his answer.